# r geom_map seems to require a region column in the map

Tags: r, ggplot2

Recently some code I've been using to make facet maps has started to give me this warning message

```
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'region'.
```

The map file I have created, called worldMap, has the following columns

```
"long"  "lat"   "order" "hole"  "piece" "group" "id"
```

And the data source has the following columns

```
"scenario" "id"       "value"
```

The code that generates the error is

```
gg <- ggplot(data = d, aes(map_id = id))
gg <- gg + geom_map(aes(fill = value), map = worldMap)
```

If I add a new column to the map that has the value of id like this

```
worldMap$region <- worldMap$id
```

the warning message disappears. But why do I need to do this? The help text for the map option of geom_map says

> It must contain columns x or long, y or lat, and region **or** id.

The code in geom_map that seems relevant is

```
stopifnot(is.data.frame(map))
    if (!is.null(map$lat)) 
        map$y <- map$lat
    if (!is.null(map$long)) 
        map$x <- map$long
    if (!is.null(map$region)) 
        map$id <- map$region
```

Anyway, I can solve my problem by just adding the column "region" but that seems like a kludge.

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? I tested with artificial map data where I replaced region with id, and could not reproduce the problem.